# Localize <img> tag "alt" text in MVC Razor View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, internationalization

This is the code that I currently have:

```
<img id="imgLoading" src="../../Content/images/uploading.gif" alt="@MyResource.LoadingText" />
```

and this is the rendered html:

```
<img id="imgLoading" src="../../Content/images/uploading.gif" alt="
  Product list loading...
" style="display: inline; ">
```

the rendered html has undesired new line before and after resource text. Is this the proper way to localize image alt text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that's fine, it's valid HTML. Nothing to worry about. If you want to get rid of the new lines and whitespaces fix your RESX file.

Comment: wow i was not even aware it's ME that's adding the new lines..thanks for helping me again Dimitrov

Comment: i introduced the newlines by trying to make the resx xml looking pretty...this is what i get for trying to do good work! :P